# Insert at least 3 week old date in oracle column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to enter value in Insert_TS column(default systimestamp) having following condition:-

-The value must be at least 3 weeks old from sysdate.

At least here refers to minimum, but I am not sure if it means sysdate-21 or something else.

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: Well as 3 weeks = 21 days then SYSTIMESTAMP -21 would appear to be the answer but it sounds like you are not really sure that that is the requirement. Perhaps you should go back to whoever has that requirement and clarify it.

Comment: @BriteSponge Thanks for your comment. Yes, SYSTIMESTAMP -21 appear to be the answer.But the confusing thing is the word "at  least" . If it means any date which is SYSTIMESTAMP -21 then how that date should be calculated?

Comment: The answer by @MT0 below covers the 21 days thing to the letter. The confusion is something that only you can resolve and it might be a hint that the user actually has a more complex requirement that they don't realise they need to clarify. Never assume, always check.

Comment: Why are you asking a bunch of strangers on the internet to guess what your requirement means? Why don't you ask the person who gave your the requirement?

Comment: @APC I just wanted to know if I am thinking in the right direction and if any one can guide me. I think its a good platform to reach out to multi-skilled strangers to get some ideas/hints which would help. Anyways,I got my answer and would like to Thank everyone who shared their views to guide me on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (
  your_column
) VALUES (
  SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '21' DAY
);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO your_table (
  your_column
) VALUES (
  SYSTIMESTAMP - 21
);
```

Comment: Thanks @MT0  for the queries.

Comment: @AnuIN If this has answered your question then you can click the tick mark (below the voting buttons to the left of the answer) to indicate your preferred answer and show that your issue has been resolved.